# Blocking the web application when using a simple object.wait

Tags: java, multithreading, vaadin

i'm using a lock object on a window , i want to block :
When the user click the button "Click Me" i want to open a window containing a calendar is opened, and the user should choose a date in the calendar. The user should be blocked until he chooses the date, so I wrote this:

```
    Button button = new Button("Click Me");
    button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
synchronized (Lock.getInstance()) {
          DateChooser dateChooser = new DateChooser(new com.kopiright.xkopi.lib.type.Date(2013, 12, 9));



          UI.getCurrent().addWindow(dateChooser);


              System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!I'm waiting ...");
            try {
              Lock.getInstance().wait();
              System.out.println("I'm waiting ...");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

         }

        }

      });
```

When the user click the button the window is not showed and the the page waits infinitely.
The problem is that i'm blocking the principle class which lunching the application.
So how to prevent this.
Should i create a seperate thread that shows the DateChooser window.

Here's the notify call : 
in the DateChooser class i wrote this :

```
@Override
public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
  synchronized(Lock.getInstance()) {
  String date = String.valueOf(event.getProperty().getValue());
  Calendar  cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
  cal.setTime((java.util.Date) event.getProperty().getValue());

  setSelectedDate(new NotNullDate(cal));
  this.close();
  Lock.getInstance().notify();
  }
 }
```

Here's the Lock class

```
public class Lock
 {
  private static Lock lockInstance;

public static  Lock getInstance()
{
 if (lockInstance == null)
   {lockInstance = new Lock();
    System.out.println("Creating a lock instance ...");}
    return lockInstance;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you are mistaking two `wait` concepts: GUI block, and synchronization.

in your case, you don't need to sync anything, you just have to find a way to **disable** the opener GUI window when the user clicks the button, and show the new one.

Comment: i searched a lot about how to disable the current page until the user choose a date but i didn't find something useful. Thank you :)

Comment: i think you can simply do `window.setVisible(false)`, but i'm no swing expert and there are better ways for sure ;)

Answer (score 2):

In vaadin the same web principles, of http request-response, apply. When the user clicks the button a request is made, in order for the window to be shown the response from the server must complete. But this does not happen as the thread gets blocked.

Moreover to achieve what you describe you do not need threading control. Just display the calendar on a modal window, remove close controls from the window and only close the window with the value change listener of the dateChooser object.

Assuming DateChooser is a vaadin Window you can call `setModal(true);` to make it modal. Also have a look in book of vaadin `https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.sub-window.html` .